# How to use connection pooling in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, connection, connection-pooling

I am supposed to use JBoss connection pooling for my application.Right now I don't have any idea about that. I Googled but couldn't get any good link.
Can you please share any good link which describes how to define data source, create and use connections in Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is what you r looking for:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/89511/JBoss/Connection-Pooling

This snippet returns the database connection as declared in the xml fragment:

```
InitialContext jndiCntx = new InitialContext();  
DataSource ds = (DataSource)jndiCntx.lookup("java:/yourdsname"); 
connection = ds.getConnection();
```